# How we filter the search base on post-meta tags

Tags: search

I am using my custom filter. So in this search there are many checkboxes (have city name) and user selected some of them the post show the search result base on the checkbox.
First i sotre the city/state name by using the `add_post_meta`

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'post_state' , $state, true);
```

So after that when user filter the post. i am using the code

```
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'sortbydestination' ) :
$stateName = $_POST['stateName'];

unset($_POST);
endif;
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 30,
            'paged' => $paged, 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_query' => array(
                            'key' => 'post_state',
                            'value' => array($stateName)

                            ) 
            );
```

The checkbox html is generated by jquery which is

```
jQuery('#state_div').append('<label><input type="checkbox" name="stateName['+ state_arr[x] +']" id="" value="'+ state_arr[x] +'" >' + state_arr[x] + '</label');
```

So the name of the `input` is a `array` it self, which give me values like this

```
stateName[cityname1];
stateName[cityname2];
stateName[cityname3];
stateName[cityname4];
```

and so on. So someone tell me wether i am using right way to get these data or make correct `query` or not. Thanks

Comment: You comparison operator is `=`, yet you feed the metaquery an array as a value. That cannot work. Simply pass `$stateName` as a value.

Comment: I did that to. I remove the `'compare' => '='` but it not working. It show me all the posts. so what can i do now

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you got the meta_query wrong. Check documentation in [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Your query should be:

```
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 30,
            'paged' => $paged, 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                 'key' => 'post_state',
                                 'value' => $stateName,
                                 'compare' => '=' // not necesary by default is "="
                                )
                            ) 
            );
```

Basically you need to pass inside the meta_query array, another array with the key and value. Also $stateName should be a var.

Comment: i just remove the `'compare' => '='`, But after that its still not working. It show me the all posts.

Comment: did you copy the code exactly as mine? leave compare there, or remove previous ","

Comment: Yes i am using the same code as you suggested me. There is one problem i think, i am getting the data by `post` using this `$stateName = $_POST['stateName'];` in html `stateName[]` is array. so i am using right way to get it or not.

Comment: You should edit your question and post the whole code. HTML included. I can´t help you out with that little info

Comment: check my question now i upadate it